# How can I detect if the user closes a script Python?

Tags: python

I am currently using atexit to monitor if a user closes a script, but this only registers keyboard interruptions how can I register if a user closes a script EG when they exit the terminal when the script is running? For Mac and Windows

Comment: which operating system ?

Comment: Mac and Windows @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Comment: [edit] your question to put that in.

Comment: Done @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Comment: You may want to use signal handler to detect if a program is sent signal to terminate. https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html

Comment: I think this kind of depends on what terminal you're running within, and how they tear down.